# I encounter an exception while saving with EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

> Inner Exception 1:
> MySqlException: Duplicate entry '08dad56f-8499-4b4f-81b7-53c3ca5c06eb' for key 'PRIMARY'

```cs
Account? account=null;

using (AppDbContext context = new())
{
   account = context.Set<Account>()
             .Include(e=>e.AccountCategory)
             .First()
}

if (account == null) return;

var inv= new Invoice()
{
     Name=str,
     Account = account,
     InvoiceItems = GetInvoiceItems()
};

var _context=new AppDbContext();
_context.Set<Invoice>().Add(inv);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The text of the inner exception is telling you exactly the problem.

Comment: Perhaps GetInvoiceItems() is returning existing rows, and then SaveChanges is trying ton INSERT them as Invoice is Added.

Comment: You haven't attached the AccountCategory, so when you add the invoice to the new context, it believes you want to create a new AccountCategory as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF DbContexts work with tracking references of objects which lets them determine when looking at an entity whether it has been updated or possibly something that needs to be inserted. EF doesn't track everything in a database to make these determinations so you have to follow some basic rules to ensure it works the way you expect.

Your issue is caused because you are using 2 separate DbContext instances to perform the update. 1 to read the account, and one to save teh new Invoice. However, invoice has a reference to the account you read from the first DbContext and this new DbContext doesn't know that it reflects an existing Account record.

As a general rule you should work within the scope of a single DbContext and references to entities should ideally not leave the scope of the DbContext. By all means they can, but they are effectively detached entities and need special treatment if you are going to reference them.

Single DbContext:

```
using (AppDbContext context = new())
{
    account = context.Set<Account>()
             .Include(e=>e.AccountCategory)
             .Single(x => x.AccountId == accountId);


    if (account == null) return;

    var inv = new Invoice()
    {
        Name=str,
        Account = account,
        InvoiceItems = GetInvoiceItems(context)
    };

    context.Set<Invoice>().Add(inv);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The important details here. All operations should use the single DbContext. This includes calls to do things like getting invoice items, so if you are `using` scope your DbContext, pass the DbContext instance so that it is tracking all entities you load rather than having a bunch of separate DbContexts used to load entities.

Better, with navigation properties where an Account has a collection of Invoices associated to it, this can be simplified:

```
using (AppDbContext context = new())
{
    account = context.Set<Account>()
        .Include(e => e.Invoices)
        .Single(x => x.AccountId == accountId);

    if (account == null) return;

    var inv = new Invoice()
    {
        Name=str,
        InvoiceItems = GetInvoiceItems(context)
    };

    account.Invoices.Add(inv);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Since the DbContext is tracking the Account we can create the invoice, associate it to the account by adding to the Invoices collection and EF works out all of the FK associations and references needed automatically.

Doing it the way you have done, you will need to associate any and all references to the DbContext that will be saving the new entity. This can get messy if DbContext scopes are not ended for any reason or the read entities aren't first detached.  With the code you had, and assuming the GetInvoiceItems method is scoping its own DbContext, the following should work:

```
using (AppDbContext context = new())
{
   account = context.Set<Account>()
             .Include(e=>e.AccountCategory)
             .First()
}

if (account == null) return;

var inv= new Invoice()
{
     Name=str,
     Account = account,
     InvoiceItems = GetInvoiceItems()
};

var _context=new AppDbContext();
_context.Attach(account);
_context.Attach(account.AccountCategory);
foreach(var invoiceItem in inv.InvoiceItems)
    _context.Attach(invoiceItem);

_context.Set<Invoice>().Add(inv);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Here we attach the account and the invoice items to the DbContext instance that is going to save the Invoice.  Attaching entities can lead to other exceptions being raised if the entity is still tracked by another DbContext, or the context you are attaching it to is already tracking another instance of the same record. It may work here, but fail when you try it in other areas, or worse, work but fail in certain scenarios at runtime just due to the references involved in that particular scenario.

Comment: Thank you.. I have applied the programming instructions that contain (_context.Attach.....) The method was effective.. Thank you